# Flipkart Affiliate - Can I track the status of an order made through my website?

Tags: javascript, html, affiliate, flipkart-api, affiliates

I am being an affiliate to flipkart and I am advertising flipkart products on my website.

My requirement is this:

If a user redirects to flipkart from my website and purchases a product, can we get the order/purchase id of that particular purchase and can we track it's status and show it in my website.

Comment: Is Flipkart exposing any API to you?

Comment: I didn't see any API's from the flipkart. But I wanted to be sure that this is not possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for information on a product rather than looking for assistance with code.

Comment: @RajKumar See anything is possible and there WILL be a way. It would be better if you find some possible ways, try something, if you face issues then ask here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flipkart product api you can track orders with 2 extra parameters.

if you are not using flipkart product api, just using their advertisement banners and links on your website then you can only see product details in the report section such as price and category of product.

Note: Flipkart doesn't return any order id.

Comment: "If you are using flipkart product api you can track orders with 2 extra parameters." Yes I am using flipkart product API, but I didn't see any parameters related to tracking.